Azure Postgresql Felxible server: pg_dump aborting because of server version mismatch
I am trying to take backup of Azure Postgresql Flexible Server using pg_dump command. I have followed this article.
My database is on Postgresql v15.6, but when I connected to the Azure Postgresql flexible Server via Powershell, the pg_dump installed on that instance is using v14.11.
I know, to take the backup both pg_dump and Postgresql should be using same version.
But my question is, why pg_dump is on different version when I am using Postgresql 15.6?
Another question is, what should I do now to upgrade pg_dump on a Azure Managed Postgresql server to take backup?
